useContext wrap throw error even the components is wrapped [React Native]
i wrap all of my components and screen inside the CartProvide but its still show "useCart must be used within a CartProvider"
I wanna show the receipt of the total orders but it show the error
below is my code for CartContext
type CartItem = {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  imageUrl: any;
  type: "FOOD" | "DRINK";
};

interface CartContextType {
  orders: CartItem[];
  addToCart: (item: CartItem) => void;
  clearCart: () => void;
}

const CartContext = createContext<CartContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const CartProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState<CartItem[]>([]);

  const addToCart = (item: CartItem) => {
    setOrders((prevOrders) => [...prevOrders, item]);
  };

  const clearCart = () => {
    setOrders([]);
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ orders, addToCart, clearCart }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCart = () => {
  const context = useContext(CartContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useCart must be used within a CartProvider");
  }
  return context;
};


my index
const index = () => {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Greet />
        <Menu />
      </View>
    </CartProvider>
  );
};

and my Cart screen
const Cart = () => {
  const { orders } = useCart(); // Fetch cart orders

  
  const total = orders.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.price, 0);

  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <ScrollView>
        <Header />
        <CartComp
          itemPrices={orders.map((item) => item.price)}
          menus={orders.map((item) => item.name)}
          total={total}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </CartProvider>
  );
};

i already wrap all of that inside of CartProvider but it still show the error, how this could happen?

Why are you rendering multiple CartProvider components? In the code you have shared the Cart component is rendering another CartProvider, so it can't possibly access that context. Is there another CartProvider higher up the ReactTree from Cart to provide it the context? Based on the error it seems there isn't.

You need to wrap  component with  not inside 

I think the error throws because of double-wrapping the same content inside CartProvider. In index.ts, you wrap the whole app with a CartProvider, but you aslo wrap the Cart screen component inside another CartProvider.
It can produce issues related to context creation and their appearances in the tree. As a result, the useCart hook checks the context, finds it undefined, and throws the error message which you define in useCart hook:
export const useCart = () => {
  const context = useContext(CartContext);
  if (!context) { // true
    throw new Error("useCart must be used within a CartProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

You only need a single Provider to manage the state for the same nested content within your app. Use separate providers only when wrapping different parts of your app that require their own context. For shared state among the same nested components, stick to one Provider.
BTW, it's better to wrap only the part of your app that actually uses the context in the Provider. This minimizes unnecessary re-renders for components that don't rely on the context, improving performance.
I hope it helps:)
